# Any way to get JS object using scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, html-parsing, scrapy

I am using scrapy to gather schedule information on uslpro website. The site I am crawling is http://uslpro.uslsoccer.com/schedules/index_E.html.

The content of the page is rendered when the page is loaded. So I can't get the table data directly from source code. I looked at the source code and found that the schedule objects are stored in one object.

Here is the JavaScript Code.

```
preRender: function(){
var gmsA=diiH2A(DIISnapshot.gamesHolder);
....
```

This gmsA object has all schedule information. Is there any way to get this JS object using scrapy? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, you have multiple options to choose from:

- parse the javascript file containing the data (which is I'm describing below)
- use `Scrapy` with [`scrapyjs`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) tool
- automate a real browser with the help of [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

---

Okay, the first option (is arguably the most complicated).

The page is loaded via a separate call to a `.js` file which contains the information about matches and teams in two separate objects:

```
DIISnapshot.gms = {
    "4428801":{"code":"1","tg":65672522,"fg":"2953156","fac":"22419","facn":"Blackbaud Stadium","tm1":"13380700","tm2":"22310","sc1":"1","sc2":"1","gmapply":"","dt":"22-MAR-2014","tim":"30-DEC-1899 19:30:00.0000","se":"65672455","modst":"","gmlabel":"","golive":0,"gmrpt":"67842863","urlvideo":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHi6_nnuAsQ","urlaudio":""}
  , "4428803":{"code":"2","tg":65672522,"fg":"2953471","fac":"1078448","facn":"StubHub Center","tm1":"33398866","tm2":"66919078","sc1":"1","sc2":"3","gmapply":"","dt":"22-MAR-2014","tim":"30-DEC-1899 22:30:00.0000","se":"65672455","modst":"","gmlabel":"","golive":0,"gmrpt":"67846731","urlvideo":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLaRaTi7BgE","urlaudio":""}
    ...   
  , "5004593":{"code":"217","tg":65672522,"fg":"66919058","fac":"66919059","facn":"Bonney Field","tm1":"934394","tm2":"65674034","sc1":"0","sc2":"2","gmapply":"3","dt":"27-SEP-2014","tim":"30-DEC-1899 22:30:00.0000","se":"65672455","modst":"21-SEP-2014 1:48:26.5710","gmlabel":"FINAL","golive":0,"gmrpt":"72827154","urlvideo":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPhL8Ktkz4M","urlaudio":""}
};  

DIISnapshot.tms = {
    "13380700":{"name":"Orlando City SC","club":"","nick":"Orlando","primarytg":"65672522"}
    ...
  , "8969532":{"name":"Pittsburgh Riverhounds","club":"","nick":"Pittsburgh","primarytg":"65672522"}
  , "934394":{"name":"Harrisburg City Islanders","club":"","nick":"Harrisburg","primarytg":"65672522"}
};
```

And things are getting a bit more difficult because the URL to that `js` file is also constructed with javascript in the following `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var DIISnapshot = {
  goLive: function(gamekey) {
    clickpop1=window.open('http://uslpro.uslsoccer.com/scripts/runisa.dll?M2:gp::72013+Elements/DisplayBlank+E+2187955++'+gamekey+'+65672455','clickpop1','toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,top=100,left=100,width=315,height=425');
  }
};
var DIISchedule = {
  MISL_lgkey: '36509042',
  sename:'2014',
  sekey: '65672455',
  lgkey: '2792331',
  tg: '65672522',
  ...

  fetchInfo:function(){
    var fname = DIISchedule.tg;
    if (fname === '') fname = DIISchedule.sekey;
    new Ajax.Request('/schedules/' + DIISchedule.seSeq + '/' + fname + '.js?'+rand4(),{asynchronous: false});
    DIISnapshot.gamesHolder = DIISnapshot.gms;
    DIISnapshot.teamsHolder = DIISnapshot.tms;
    DIISnapshot.origTeams = [];
    for (var teamkey in DIISnapshot.tms) DIISnapshot.origTeams.push(teamkey);
  },
  ...

    DIISchedule.scheduleLoaded = true;
  }
}
document.observe('dom:loaded',DIISchedule.init);
</script>
```

Okay, let's use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) HTML parser and [`slimit` javascript parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit) to get the dynamic part (that `tg` value is the name of the `js` with the data) used to construct the URL, then make a request to a URL, parse the javascript and print out the matches:

```
import json
import random
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor

# start a session
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36'}
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('http://uslpro.uslsoccer.com/schedules/index_E.html', headers=headers)

# get the dynamic part of the JS url
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
script = soup.find('script', text=lambda x: x and 'var DIISchedule' in x)
tg = re.search(r"tg: '(\d+)',", script.text).group(1)

# request to JS url
js_url = "http://uslpro.uslsoccer.com/schedules/2014/{tg}.js?{rand}".format(tg=tg, rand=random.randint(1000, 9999))
response = session.get(js_url, headers=headers)

# parse js
parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(response.content)
matches, teams = [json.loads(node.right.to_ecma())
                  for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree)
                  if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and isinstance(node.left, ast.DotAccessor)]

for match in matches.itervalues():
    print teams[match['tm1']]['name'], '%s : %s' % (match['sc1'], match['sc2']), teams[match['tm2']]['name']
```

Prints:

```
Arizona United SC 0 : 2 Orange County Blues FC
LA Galaxy II 1 : 0 Seattle Sounders FC Reserves
LA Galaxy II 1 : 3 Harrisburg City Islanders
New York Red Bulls Reserves 0 : 1 OKC Energy FC
Wilmington Hammerheads FC 2 : 1 Charlotte Eagles
Richmond Kickers 3 : 2 Harrisburg City Islanders
Charleston Battery 0 : 2 Orlando City SC
Charlotte Eagles 0 : 2 Richmond Kickers
Sacramento Republic FC 2 : 1 Dayton Dutch Lions FC
OKC Energy FC 0 : 5 LA Galaxy II
...
```

The part printing the list of matches is for demonstration purposes. You can use `matches` and `teams` dictionaries to output the data in a format you need.

<sup>As this is not a popular tag I don't expect any upvotes - most importantly, it was an interesting challenge for me.</sup>